# How to infer trim loop from rational bspline surface

Tags: computational-geometry, spline, .obj

#### My primary question is this:

Given a rational bspline surface, how do we express its boundaries in `curv2/vp` notation?

---

#### Background:

I'm reading through the [documentation of the .obj file format](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/obj/). I'm a little confused by the documentation for the curves that comprise trim loops around bspline surfaces. For a standard, four-sided patch, the boundary is specified by four curves of the following format:

```
curv2  vp1  vp2   vp3. . .

    Free-form geometry statement.

    Specifies a 2D curve on a surface and its control points. A 2D
    curve is used as an outer or inner trimming curve, as a special
    curve, or for connectivity.

    vp is the parameter vertex reference number for the control point.
    You can specify multiple control points. A minimum of two control
    points is required for a 2D curve.

    The control points are parameter vertices because the curve must
    lie in the parameter space of some surface. For a non-rational
    curve, the control vertices can be 2D. For a rational curve, the
    control vertices can be 2D or 3D. The third coordinate (weight)
    defaults to 1.0 if omitted.
```

The "parameter vertex reference number" refers to the "control points" specified in the (u,v,w) parameter space:

```
vp u v w

    Free-form geometry statement.

    Specifies a point in the parameter space of a curve or surface.

    The usage determines how many coordinates are required. Special
    points for curves require a 1D control point (u only) in the
    parameter space of the curve. Special points for surfaces require a
    2D point (u and v) in the parameter space of the surface. Control
    points for non-rational trimming curves require u and v
    coordinates. Control points for rational trimming curves require u,
    v, and w (weight) coordinates.

    u is the point in the parameter space of a curve or the first
    coordinate in the parameter space of a surface.

    v is the second coordinate in the parameter space of a surface.

    w is the weight required for rational trimming curves. If you do
    not specify a value for w, it defaults to 1.0.

    NOTE: For additional information on parameter vertices, see the
    curv2 and sp statements
```

These definitions yield two confusing issues for me:

1. Each `vp` requires an additional coordinate for rational bspline trim curves: a weight, w.
2. The `vp` "control points" are specified in parameter space (u,v,w), but the control points for the surface are in physical space (x,y,z,w).

which raise the following, more specific questions.

#### Specific Questions:

1. Is the value of w in (u,v,w) simply computed using the weight function from the rational bspline surface at the point (u,v)?
2. If the parameter space is just a square, then why would we ever need to represent the boundary with anything but a straight line in parameter space--regardless of whether or not the physical boundary is a polynomial function of the parameters?
3. If we have an exact representation of the boundary in terms of the physical-space control points that generate the surface, how do we infer what the parameter-space control points must be to exactly reproduce the same boundary?